# Pandas - Adding missing column automatically to Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a list that contains all possible columns a pandas Dataframe can contain.

```
possible_values = ['apples','banana','orange']
```

I am trying to perform a check such that if a Dataframe does not have all the columns as per the above list then the column needs to be added to the Dataframe with value set to 0

For example if the Dataframe I have contains the below column, then the other two missing column need to be added

```
df.columns = ['apples']
```

Expected output

```
df.columns = ['apples','banana','orange']
```

Comment: simply reindex: `df.reindex(possible_values,fill_value=0,axis=1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can loop through the columns like so and create a new column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'apples' : [1,2,3]})
possible_values = ['apples','banana','orange']
for val in possible_values:
    if val not in df.columns:
        df[val] = 0
df
```

output:

```
    apples  banana  orange
0   1       0       0
1   2       0       0
2   3       0       0
```

Answer (score 6):

Something like this should work:

```
for fruit in set(possible_values).difference(df.columns):
    df.insert(len(df.columns), fruit, 0)
```

`set.difference` gives you the columns *not* present in your Dataframe. The insert command then expects the position where to insert (in this case the end), the name and the default value (0)

EDIT: changed from `df.columns.difference(possible_values)` to `set(possible_values).difference(df.columns)`

Comment: this just  returned one column apples for me. `import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'apples' : [1,2,3]})
possible_values = ['apples','banana','orange']
for fruit in df.columns.difference(possible_values):
    df.insert(len(df.columns), fruit, 0)
df`

Comment: You are right, I calculated the difference the wrong way round. I updated the solution